code after async method doesn't get executed
below is my code, after the async call await InvokeMyRpcClientAsync(inputNumber), the rest of the code doesn't get hit in debug mode (also in the console the text is not printed):
await MyFiboRpcCall("10");

static async Task MyFiboRpcCall(string inputNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("my RPC Client");

    await InvokeMyRpcClientAsync(inputNumber);  // Await the async task
    
    // below line doesn't get printed
    Console.WriteLine(" RPC call completed. Press [enter] to exit."); 
    // also in debug this line doesn't get hit

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task InvokeMyRpcClientAsync(string inputNumber)
{
    using var rpcClient = new MyRpcClient();

    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Requesting fib({0})", inputNumber);
    var response = await rpcClient.CallAsync(inputNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(" [.] Got '{0}'", response); // this gets printed   
}

The full code is here:  (I'm doing a tutorial)
I tried surrounding the await call with try catch, there was no exceptions.

Have you added a breakpoint to MyFiboRpcCall and do step-by-step debugging? If so, what was the result?

I debug step by step (F10) until I reach Console.WriteLine(" [.] Got '{0}'", response);, inside InvokeMyRpcClientAsync after that the debug ends

Did you override ToString method for response? Maybe it can't provide it as string if you put complex logic in it. Also does Quick Watch display smth about response during debug?

"Debug ends" means what exactly..? Does your session crash? There might be a critical error that ends your process. Or maybe the method just doesn't return for a long time.

To my previous comment, also check Dispose method of MyRpcClient if you write your own. Maybe it can't dispose properly on method completion.

Debug ends -> the console app gets focused back, VS stays in debug mode,
the response has the corect value and it is printed in the console,
"RPC call completed. Press [enter] to exit." never gets printed

@Auditive Dispose calls connection.Close() without any exceptions being raised (I tried adding try catch and debugged it)

Found the problem,
RpcClient.Dispose has also a channel.Close(); on github,
on the tutorial page there's no channel.Close();,
so the github version works, the one the tutorial page doesn't work.
(I have no idea how the channel var of type RabbitMQ.Client.IModel was preventing the code from continuing)
Probably my Q/A doesn't follow some rules, if I get another close I'll delete the whole thing. (update: not allowed to delete it)
